# Connecting a CollectionView to a ViewController, Getting Error when connecting dataSource-Swift-XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I can connect the delegate, however, when connecting the data source I am getting the following error:

> 2015-07-13 16:45:17.529 paintApp[4628:168318] -[UIView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a12651c60
>   2015-07-13 16:45:17.539 paintApp[4628:168318] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a12651c60'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f67b75 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109cf7bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f6ec8d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ec66fc ___forwarding_** + 988
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ec6298 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001090a5286 -[UICollectionViewData _updateItemCounts] + 296
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001090a7469 -[UICollectionViewData numberOfSections] + 22
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010909158e -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _getSizingInfos] + 348
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000109092689 -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:] + 526
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010908deff -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout] + 257
>       10  UIKit                               0x00000001090a53f0 -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData] + 67
>       11  UIKit                               0x00000001090a5ac9 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:] + 54
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010906e198 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 170
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000108ab3303 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d463de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d458a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d45887e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d3c663e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d3c774a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
>       19  UIKit                               0x0000000108a3795d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
>       20  UIKit                               0x0000000108a3866a -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2684
>       21  UIKit                               0x0000000108a37005 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
>       22  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010c58d253 **31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e9c9bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e92705 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
>       25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e924c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e91906 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       27  UIKit                               0x0000000108a36a72 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
>       28  UIKit                               0x0000000108a39870 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       29  paintApp                            0x0000000107d7272e top_level_code + 78
>       30  paintApp                            0x0000000107d7276a main + 42
>       31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a4d3145 start + 1
>       32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Here is my view controller class :

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerGallery: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var tableData: [String] = ["img1" , "img2"]
var tableImages: [String] = ["file1.png", "file2.png"]

var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame) 
    collectionView.dataSource = self 
    collectionView.delegate = self 
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self,     forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView) 

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view. 

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : ColViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath : indexPath) as ColViewCell
    cell.labelCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named : tableImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell //UICollectionViewCell()
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Cell \(indexPath.row) selcted")
}

}
```

Here is my 'cell' class where have connected the cells image and label to:

```
import UIKit

class ColViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var imgCell: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var labelCell: UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your error is self-explanative enough. In place, where you set `collectionView.dataSource` you have an error source - instead of something implementing `UICollectionViewDataSource` you set `UIView` instance.

I think, you need something like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView.dataSource = self;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure I have set collectionView.dataSource anywhere? I have used the following to try correct :

Comment: var collectionView: UICollectionView! 


override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame)

        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

Comment: Oh, I have changed it to what I think you mean? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, thats it. So, does it work now? Looks like it should

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder?

Comment: I am using interface builder

Comment: Is your `collectionView` present in IB? If yes - remove it from there

Comment: Remove the whole collection view ? I deleted it and ran it but i'm obviously then getting a plain white screen when I run this in simulator

Comment: We get to the point - your IB collection view is not the one created in your code. Just use simple ViewController in your IB, and set its custom class to `ViewControllerGallery`