# iOS: put UICollectionView in a separate class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to implement UICollectionView with custom cells, and previously I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

and inside I implemented

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

and it's working fine. Now I want to implement more functions related to cell selection, but I also want to conform to MVC pattern so I'm trying to move the UICollectionView implementation to another file. Then I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBoutlet var grid: UICollectionView!
    ovverride func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        grid = GridView(grid.frame, GridLayout()) //GridLayout() is the layout file working fine
    }
 }
```

and another file:

```
class GridView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {}
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}
}
```

But then if running it'll give error:

```
collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I checked the link here: [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388118/connecting-a-collectionview-to-a-viewcontroller-getting-error-when-connecting-d), and tried to do this in the ViewController:

```
grid.dataSource = grid as! UICollectionViewDataSource?
grid.delegate = grid as! UICollectionViewDelegate?
```

But it's not working. May I know how to fix this?

**EDIT**
Class AppDelegate gives the error. And I've also tried to set the initializer of GridView:

```
override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(...)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Check your model array not nil

Answer (score 2):

You should try setting the datasource and delegate of `GridView` inside the initialiser `(frame:, layout:)` of `GridView` class.

```
override init(...) {
    super.init(...)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}
```

And can you please mention the exact line that is giving the error? Maybe you are still using some `UICollectionView` related code in your `ViewController`?

Answer (score -1):

Are you tried;

```
grid.dataSource = self
grid.delegate = self
```

If it works, after this you can customize your collection views by using tags in same delegate and data source functions.